# How to mock useNavigate hook in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-router-dom

I have a custom hook which uses `useNavigate` hook from `react-router-dom`. I just want to add a test which checks that an expected value is passed to the hook. The hook just stores and retrieve value of a query param in the URL.

Here's how my custom hook looks like -

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSearchParam } from 'react-use';

// Default value for the tokens
export const END_PAGE_TOKEN = '';

// Stores pagination tokens in react state and URL query param
export const usePaginationParams = () => {

  // Gets 'token' query param from the URL
  const token = useSearchParam('token');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return {
    getCurrentPageToken: () => decodeURIComponent(token || END_PAGE_TOKEN),
    setCurrentPageToken: (pageToken: string) => {
      if (pageToken && pageToken !== END_PAGE_TOKEN) {
        // Sets 'token' query param to the URL
        navigate(`?token=${encodeURIComponent(pageToken)}`);
      } else {
        // Go to the first page
        navigate('');
      }
    },
  };
};
```

And here's how I am testing it -

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { usePaginationParams } from './usePaginationParams';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSearchParam } from 'react-use';

let mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  mockedNavigate = jest.fn();
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    useNavigate: mockedNavigate,
  };
});

jest.mock('react-use', () => ({
  useSearchParam: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockedUseSearchParam = useSearchParam as jest.MockedFunction<typeof useSearchParam>;
const mockedUseNavigate = useNavigate as jest.MockedFunction<typeof useNavigate>;

const TEST_TOKEN = 'TEST_TOKEN';

describe('usePaginationParams', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    if (mockedUseNavigate) {
      mockedUseNavigate.mockClear();
    }
    if (mockedNavigate) {
      mockedNavigate.mockClear();
    }
    if (mockedUseSearchParam) {
      mockedUseSearchParam.mockClear();
    }
  });
  it('reads query param correctly from URL', () => {
    mockedUseSearchParam.mockReturnValueOnce(TEST_TOKEN);
    const { result } = renderHook(() => {
      const { getCurrentPageToken } = usePaginationParams();
      return getCurrentPageToken();
    });
    expect(mockedUseSearchParam).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockedUseNavigate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result.current).toBe(TEST_TOKEN);
  });
  it('sets query param correctly to URL', () => {
    mockedNavigate.mockImplementationOnce((to: string) => {
      console.log('mocked to ', to);
    });
    renderHook(() => {
      const { setCurrentPageToken } = usePaginationParams();
      setCurrentPageToken(TEST_TOKEN);
    });
    // expect(mockedNavigate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockedNavigate).toBeCalledWith(`?token=${TEST_TOKEN}`);
  });
});
```

The first test passes, but the second test fails with the following error -

```
expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "?token=TEST_TOKEN"

Number of calls: 0
```

Which means that the `mockedNavigate` is not being called and the `console.log` never gets printed. Is there any way I can test the invocation of the hook with the expected argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing the wrong mock. The `useNavigate()` hook returns a function, thus I have to mock that directly. I just changed it to the following code and it started passing.

```js
it('sets query param correctly to URL', () => {
    const mockImpl = jest.fn().mockImplementation((to: any) => {
      console.log('mocked to ', to);
    });
    mockedUseNavigate.mockImplementationOnce(() => mockImpl);
    renderHook(() => {
      const { setCurrentPageToken } = usePaginationParams();
      setCurrentPageToken(TEST_TOKEN);
    });
    expect(mockImpl).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockImpl).toBeCalledWith(`?token=${TEST_TOKEN}`);
  });
```